# Add event to element dynamically added inside iframe

Tags: html, jquery, iframe, jquery-events

I have an HTML code like this:

```
<iframe id="myframe">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="add-section">add section</a>
            <div>...</div>
        </li>
     <ul>
</iframe>
```

when the "add-section" link is clicked the parent `<li>` that contains this (add-section) link get duplicated and inserted after, and the code become like this.

```
<iframe id="myframe">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="add-section">add section</a>
            <div>...</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="add-section">add section</a>
            <div>...</div>
        </li>
     <ul>
</iframe>
```

I use this jQuery code to achieve this and it works just fine.

```
$($("#myframe").contents().find('.add-section')).on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parent().after("<li>"+$(this).parent().html()+"</li>");
            
});
```

My problem is when I click in the new created (add-section) link the code won't execute.

My question is how to add a click event to the newest added element inside the iframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to bind the event to the body element and then use event delegation like

```
$("#myframe").contents().find('body').on("click", '.add-section', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().after("<li>" + $(this).parent().html() + "</li>");
});
```