# How to add click event to the dynamic element of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm adding some html element to the iframe by using innerHTML like below

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('composer_frame'), iframedoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

iframedoc.body.innerHTML = "<a id='myAnch'>Click</a>";
```

and i want to write a function which should be exicute by clicking anchor "#myAnch"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add event to element dynamically added inside iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897028/add-event-to-element-dynamically-added-inside-iframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation:- Since you are trying to add a event on dynamically created element inside an iframe, so you have to bind it through parent reference.

That means based on parent element try to find-out the dynamically added element and then add event on it.(as jQuery din't recognise dynamically added element directly)

So do it like below:-

```
$("#composer_frame").contents().find('#myAnch').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Working snippet:-https://jsfiddle.net/sycf9nz6/

[This is called event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: @GlenDavidson  glad to help you buddy :):)

Comment: Thank to you too @jeffreyrampineda :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#composer_frame").contents().find("#myAnch").on('click',function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write function for element like this

```
$('#myAnch', iframedoc).click(function() {console.log("a");})
```

but you should put this code on parent html page.